# Codimension one submanifold gives cofibrant pair

Tags: reference-request, smooth-manifolds, manifolds, cw-complexes, cofibrations

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and $N$ be an embedded smooth submanifold of $M$ with $\partial M=\varnothing=\partial N$. Suppose, $\dim M-\dim N=1$, and $N$ is a **closed subset** of $M$.

> Does the inclusion map $i: N\hookrightarrow M$ a cofibration, i.e.
> does this pair $(M, N)$ have homotopy extension property?

$\bullet$ I am not assuming $N$ is compact in general. In case, $N$ is compact the uniform tubular neighborhood gives positive solution.

Can someone suggest me some references?

Comment: Milnor&Stasheff's "Characteristic Classes" Theorem 11.1 claims that tubular neghbourhoods exist in general, and cite Lang's "Introduction to differentiable manifolds" for the proof. I also believe that it should be possible to triangulate the pair $(M,N)$, so that the result follows from the general fact that a subcomplex of a CW-complex is a cofibration, see my answer to https://mathoverflow.net/q/206212/8103 and the comments there. (Not an answer as I don't have time to check these references myself!)